# How to get index of a nested field in JSON object using Loadash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have JSON object that looks like the snippet below.

I can navigate to the fields that I am interested to query, which match the pattern useful*

contents[0].mainArea[**1**].rec[**0**].attributes['useful.k1']

contents[0].mainArea[**1**].rec[**1**].attributes['useful.k1']

Is it possible to write a Lodash command that can extract/return the indices in bold above? I need the indices as I will later use these indices to create an assertion.

I am not sure where to start looking. Any ideas as to which commands I need to consider will be greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "leftArea": [],
      "mainArea": [
        {
          "key11": "val11",
          "key12": [
            {
              "subkey11": "subValue11",
              "subkey12": "subValue12"
            },
            {
              "subkey21": "subValue21",
              "subkey22": "subValue22"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "key21": "val21",
          "rec": [
            {
              "attributes": {
                "useful.k1": [
                  "value"
                ],
                "useful.k2": [
                  "value"
                ],
                "useful.k3": [
                  "value"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "attributes": {
                "useful.k1": [
                  "value"
                ],
                "useful.k2": [
                  "value"
                ],
                "useful.k3": [
                  "value"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "notuseful": "value",
              "notuseful2": [
                {
                  "key1": "value",
                  "key2": "value"
                },
                {
                  "key1": "value",
                  "key2": "value"
                },
                {
                  "key1": "value",
                  "key2": "value"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one element in the "contents" array? because then the first index content[0] is important too.

Comment: And your are interested in "useful*" keys in "attributes" object in "rec" array? or this "useful*" keys can be anywhere in you json?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Emech, contents will always have one element only.

Comment: @ShrutiK take a look at my answer, it works even if there are more than one element in the contents array.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is any specific lodash command for your problem, but you can use some functions to find your desired indices by some code like below:

```js
const keys = require('lodash/keys');

function findUsefulKeys(data) {
  const indices = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.contents.length; i++) {
    const mainAreaIndiesWithUsefulKeys = findUsefulKeysInContent(data.contents[i]);
    if (mainAreaIndiesWithUsefulKeys.length > 0) {
      indices.push({
        contentIndex: i,
        mainAreaIndices: mainAreaIndiesWithUsefulKeys
      });
    }
  }
  return indices;
}

function findUsefulKeysInContent(content) {
  const mainAreaIndices = [];
  if (!content.mainArea || !content.mainArea.length || content.mainArea.length === 0) {
    return mainAreaIndices;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < content.mainArea.length; i++) {
    const recIndices = findRecsWithUsefulKeysInMainArea(content.mainArea[i]);
    if (recIndices.length > 0) {
      mainAreaIndices.push({
        mainAreaIndex: i,
        recIndices: recIndices
      });
    }
  }
  return mainAreaIndices;
}

function findRecsWithUsefulKeysInMainArea(mainArea) {
  const recIndices = [];
  if (!mainArea.rec || !mainArea.rec.length || mainArea.rec.length === 0) {
    return recIndices;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < mainArea.rec.length; i++) {
    if (recHasUsefulKeys(mainArea.rec[i])) {
      recIndices.push(i);
    }
  }
  return recIndices;
}

function recHasUsefulKeys(rec) {
  if (!rec || !rec.attributes) {
    return false;
  }

  const attributeKeys = keys(rec.attributes);
  for (let i = 0; i < attributeKeys.length; i++) {
    if (attributeKeys[i].startsWith('useful')) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// data is you json data 
const data = require('./data');
console.log(JSON.stringify(findUsefulKeys(data)));
```

The above code with your example json data will print

```js
[{"contentIndex":0,"mainAreaIndices":[{"mainAreaIndex":1,"recIndices":[0,1]}]}]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop to get the value from JSON like below:

```js
const data = {
  "contents": [
    {
      "leftArea": [],
      "mainArea": [
        {
          "key11": "val11",
          "key12": [
            {
              "subkey11": "subValue11",
              "subkey12": "subValue12"
            },
            {
              "subkey21": "subValue21",
              "subkey22": "subValue22"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "key21": "val21",
          "rec": [
            {
              "attributes": {
                "useful.k1": [
                  "value"
                ],
                "useful.k2": [
                  "value"
                ],
                "useful.k3": [
                  "value"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "attributes": {
                "useful.k1": [
                  "value"
                ],
                "useful.k2": [
                  "value"
                ],
                "useful.k3": [
                  "value"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "notuseful": "value",
              "notuseful2": [
                {
                  "key1": "value",
                  "key2": "value"
                },
                {
                  "key1": "value",
                  "key2": "value"
                },
                {
                  "key1": "value",
                  "key2": "value"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}



const useful = data.contents[0].mainArea[1].rec;

for(const v in useful)
  {
    //console.log(useful[v].attributes); // Oject
    
    for( let vv in useful[v].attributes) // for for every single value
      {
        console.log(useful[v].attributes[vv]);
      }
  }
```